# SQL:How to create SQL table using some condition [Create table only when condition is true]

Tags: sql

Create table tblname if(name='stack').
Create this table only when this condition is true , So how to write this type of query?

Comment: I highly recommend reading the guide to asking a good question, because it stands this will get closed soon for not having enough information, research etc etc. And specifying too many RDBMS.

Comment: A query can't create anything, but selects data only.

Comment: Where is name coming from?, is this code in a stored program?

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert...YET!
But you can try the below query with a IF statement In Another If Statment.
It's Difficult to help if we don't know what your end goal is??

```
DECLARE @Condition Varchar(5) = 'TRUE'

IF(@Condition='True')

    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT object_id FROM sys.objects 
         WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Country]') AND type = 'U')
            BEGIN
             CREATE TABLE [dbo].Country(ID INT, Description Varchar(20))
            END
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'IGNORE - DONT CREATE TABLE'
    END;
```

Comment: OP has tagged mysql but your answer is for sql-server/mssql only and will not syntax in mysql..

Comment: Okay Thanks @P.Salmon for pointing that out - I am Sure the author can amend it if need be